# How do I resolve a Conditional format comparing two ranges?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-formula

I have a column of cells with a value
I have another column of cells with a value

Let's say G5:G15 and D20:G30

I need to compare each with a greater than or equals and less than

Can I run this through a ranged conditional format?

I.E.

> Range: G5:G15
>
> Custom Formula: =G5>=D20
>
> Format: Green Background

I've tried the above, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try custom formula:

```
=IF(G5>=D$20, 1)
```

or maybe you are after this:

```
=COUNTIF(G5, ">="&MIN($D$20:$G$30))
```

[image]

Comment: Close, more like this: 


[1]:   https://i.imgur.com/ztXgV6Q.png

Column I should turn green or red if the corresponding row in G is greater than/equal or less than.

(P.S. How do I embad an image?)

Comment: @Nazzarus next time pls doublecheck your post

Answer (score 0):

- **green:** `=COUNTIF(I2, ">="&G2)`
- **red:** `=COUNTIF(I2, "<"&G2)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a workaround, I used a new column with a subtraction of the two, and added two rules for equal to(green) or greater than zero(red) and made the fonts match.